# When user from REMOTE_ADDR visits my site my server 'visits' my page too

Tags: php

I'm totally new in some tech stuff somy question may seem funny, however, I ask:

When user visits my page I check if i.e $_SESSION['hit'] is set. If not I count visit and write it to the db and then set $_SESSION['hit'] to 1 to avoid doubling the same visit. And then problem occurs: it writes:

1. visiting user data (i.e. REMOTE_ADDR and session_id, but
2. also writes 'visit' from address that belongs to server on which I
       have my site.

For user session_id is set but for this second visit session_id is null/empty. All these visits happen in the same time. What is going on?

Thanx for every answer.

Comment: with code example it'd be much more easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

have you written session_start() before the condition to check that session variable is set or not ?

Comment: yes I have, real user visits are written to db together with current session_id()